# Ant build error, cannot find folder

Tags: java, ant

Is there error in this line?

```
<arg line="-cp ./bin -keep -s ./src -d ./bin com.myfirst.wsServer.SayHello"/>
```

Because the eclipse console tells:

```
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\wsServerExample\src\build.xml
wsgen:
[exec] directory not found: .\src
```

Comment: Take the `.` out from `/src`.

Comment: I created a new project. but this time under the c:\ dir. it works! but anyway, i simply dont understand why it does not work in the previous setup.. is it because of the space characters?

Comment: I first tougth you could use ${basedir} but this is with ant files in your case I dont think it will work. You could try to use absolute path just to see if it would works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message suggest that you are running your script from ./src/ folder already so it migth not be able to find your src folder.

Try using path like if you were in ./src or move build.xml to your project root folder to see if this can help.

Comment: is it because of the spaces in "Documents and Settings"?

Comment: @karikari Yes good point, maybe. But I don't think its this since there is not spaces on the line that throws an error. I realy tink it must be someting like build.xml get invoked from C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\wsServerExample\src\ so obviously it does not find src and bin.